# PHP mysql adding up duplicates at result

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have a database that stores information everytime someone downloads a file. It captures name email and the date stamp everytime they download the file (as requested by client).

I want to be able connect to the database and add up all duplicate entries. So if there are 10 results with the email a@a.com it will print "a@a.com; 10 downloads."

This is what i have tried so far. However it times out on the page:

```
function userFile($id) // $id = File ID
 {
    $order = "SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE dl_id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($order);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){     
        $email = $row['email'];
        $order = "SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE email='$email'";
        $result = mysql_query($order);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        print $row['email'] . ' ' . $num_rows;
    }
 }
```

There has to be an easier or better way of doing this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_query` in new code, but if you must, **always** [escape your SQL values correctly](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have MySQL do the work for you. If I understand your requirements correctly you need a query like this:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS num_rows
FROM downloads
WHERE dl_id='$id'
GROUP BY email
```

Then your PHP code would look something like this:

```
function userFile($id) // $id = File ID
 {
    $order = "SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS `num_rows` FROM downloads WHERE dl_id='$id' GROUP BY email";
    $result = mysql_query($order);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){     
        $email = $row['email'];
        $num_rows = $row['num_rows'];
        print $email . ' ' . $num_rows;
    }
 }
```

I don't have PHP available here today, so be warned this is untested.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you for the fast reply! Im still fairly new to mysql and havent really learned all there is to it yet! Thanks again!

Comment: @EdGibbs I don't know any method to upvote an edit :P But you could upvote my answer (as it is nearly the same as yours, there's no difference, but I'd have then +10 reputation^^)

Comment: @bwoebi - done! Thanks again for the assist, and it looks like your edit came through somehow so that's all set too.

Answer (score 2):

```
function userFile ($id) // $id = File ID
{
    $order = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, email FROM downloads WHERE dl_id='$id' GROUP BY email"
    $result = mysql_query($order);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        print "{$row['email']}; {$row['count']} downloads.\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall use `GROUP BY` within `COUNT`.

```
SELECT *,COUNT(1) FROM downloads WHERE `email`='$email' GROUP BY `email`
```